# Non blocking system call and mode switch

Tags: unix, asynchronous, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

Suppose we invoke a system call for asynchronous IO. At the time of invoking system call, the mode changes from user mode to kernel mode . After invocation, the mode should immediately change back to user mode so that user application can proceed further(as it is non blocking).

Now if the mode is changed to user mode then how will kernel proceed with IO as mode is changed from kernel to user mode ? Will kernel perform asynchronous IO in user mode ?

Answer (score 6):

IO means two different things (at two different levels of abstractions):

- from an application point of view, from a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running in [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), calling any [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for Linux) related to input or output, e.g. [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), .... Notice that [aio_read(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_read.3.html) is not listed as a system call (it is some library function using other system calls, see [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html)).
- on the raw hardware, any physical input or output operation sending data (or orders) to actual IO devices (e.g. SATA disks, USB ports, etc...)

Asynchronous or synchronous IO for a process means just calling some suitable subset of system calls, since system calls are the *only* way a process can interact with the kernel, and since in user-mode no physical IO is *directly* possible.

**Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/)** (freely downloadable) to get a better view of OSes.

> Will kernel perform asynchronous IO in user mode ?

This shows some confusion. In practice, inside the kernel, physical IO is generally (and probably always) initiated by [interrupt handlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) (which might configure some [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) etc...). A hardware [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) switches the processor to "kernel-mode" (actually [supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisory_program) mode of the [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)).

A blocking system call (e.g. [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) when physical IO is needed since the data is not in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) don't block the entire computer: it is just the calling process which becomes "blocked" so is rescheduled. The kernel will schedule some other runnable process. Much later, after having the kernel handle many interrupts, the blocked process will become runnable and could be rescheduled to run.

Processes are themselves (with [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file)) one of the major [abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) (provided by the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))) to application code.

In other words, at the conceptual level, the kernel [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#SCHEDULER) is coded in some [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

See also [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/).

Comment: What about non blocking system calls in general? Can kernel perform functions in user mode (after the mode changes from kernel to user mode so that user can proceed) ?

Comment: By definition, kernel only runs in kernel mode.

Comment: So how will kernel process IO ? If kernel processes the entire IO in kernel mode then user application can't proceed further(as it's kernel mode) in case of non blocking system call.

Comment: You are really confused. I strongly recommend taking a few days to read that *Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces* book. I suspect that an entire book is needed to explain you all that, and I don't have space to write one, and time to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous IO will be performed on behalf of the process, the kernel will handle it almost as usual while the process continues to run. In blocking mode, the process is just suspended.

Kernel has access to every process space, so he can fill/read data from process user space whatever a process is currently doing.

Comment: I understand what happens in asynchronous IO. When process continues to run, the mode is changed to user mode right ? How will kernel handle the IO in user mode when user application is running? I read that kernel always performs it's operations in kernel mode only.

Comment: It looks like you have too many misconceptions. `kernel handle the IO in user mode`, no, kernel **always** handles IO in kernel mode (at least on standard OSes).

Comment: I know kernel handles IO in kernel mode. My question is when kernel is handling IO in kernel mode, how can user application continue to run as the system call is non blocking ? For user application to continue, the mode should be changed back to user mode right ?

Comment: Kernel and processes are concurrent. Read about interrupts, DMA, context-switch.